# Nothing was return from render in renderItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have DATA - array of arrays(important) with items, and trying to create flatlist:

```
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  />
```

so when I was mapping items in renderItem like that:

```
  items.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.item} key={index}>
        </View>
      );
  });
```

I have received Nothing was return error. What am I supposed to do?

Ed. https://snack.expo.io/@komarnytskiyivan/gnarly-waffle - code sandbox

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null @SinanYaman

Comment: what's inside items array?

Comment: You don't have any content inside the `<View>` tag. Is that what you are going for?

Comment: I've simplified code for better understanding @SinanYaman

Comment: Objects with keys @SifatHaque

Comment: please share a codesandbox link of your issue.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@komarnytskiyivan/gnarly-waffle @SifatHaque

Comment: You need to return from your `items.map` in your `Item` component

Comment: I think I do, could you please be more specific? @AlistairNelson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Item` you have this:

```
const Item = ({ items }) => {
  console.log(items);
  items.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item)
    if (item && index) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.item} key={index}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  });
};
```

You need to return from the `items.map` so it is `return items.map`

Comment: It will return nothing @AlistairNelson

Comment: It will return what was returned from the `map` as otherwise you aren't actually returning anything from the `Item`, hence the error in the console

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `Item` component like so :-

```
const Item = ({ items }) => {
  return items.map((item, index) => {
      return (<View style={styles.item} key={index}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>);
  });
};
```

Changes :-

- return the new array from `.map`
- return the `<View>...</View>` component
- remove the `item && index` check. Will fail when `index` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any documentation you recommend me to read to avoid such issues? @LakshyaThakur

Comment: @Pavel Umm this was not an issue that was related to React itself but more of JS. So I would say to get to know it better as you progress. Here is a good resource - https://www.theavocoder.com/complete-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  />
```

**Use renderItem like this**

```
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
     
        return (
          <View style={styles.item} key={index}>
           // Your view here
            </View>
        );
      };
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, but my task is to use renderItem with array @HamasHassan